# My Python Program can't call source code imported in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a new programmer and I wrote code as `main.py` to determine maximum and minimum and also if the values are equal:

```
def compare():

    x,y,z = 0,0,0
    x = input("Enter the First Number: ")
    y = input("Enter the Second Number: ")
    z = input("Enter the Third Number: ")
    numbers = [x,y,z]

    if numbers[0] == numbers[1]:

        if numbers[0] == numbers[2]:

            print("Numbers are Equal which is = ",numbers[0])

        else:

            print("The Maximum number is = ",max(numbers))
            print("The Minimum number is = ",min(numbers))
            
    else:

        print("The Maximum number is = ",max(numbers))
        print("The Minimum number is = ",min(numbers))

compare()
```

I did this in `run.py`:

```
import main

i = 1

while i >= 1: # I did infinite loop to make program runs repeatedly
    main
    i = i + 1
```

I expected to run without stopping but it is doing it once and it'll stopped.

Comment: This is not how imports work, at all.

Comment: You need a routine to call. If you define a method in `main` that encapsulates the sequence of code that you would like to execute, then you can import that method and execute it within another file. As it is, you've imported the code from `main` but you're attempting to execute it using invalid syntax.

Comment: The code in the module is only executed when you do `import main`, not when you type `main` by itself. And modules are only imported once, you can't import it in a loop.

Comment: @MohammedAlYahyai try `from main import compare` in your `run.py` file. Then you should be able to call the `compare` method like this: `compare()`

Comment: Just "mentioning" a variable like `main` never does anything. It doesn't work like copy and pasting the "code" that's in `main` there.

Comment: To run the `compare` function in main.py, you would need to do `main.compare()` in run.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported the main module, but you need to call the compare function from it.

You've already got some good explanation in the comments, but here's how you can fix your code in run.py:

```
import main

i = 1

while i >= 1:
    main.compare()
    i = i + 1
```

As you are a new programmer, I'd recommend this article on importing in Python: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#the-import-statement

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put the call to `compare()` in the module itself, except when the module is run as a top-level script.

Instead, call the function that the module defines in your loop.

```
def compare():

    x,y,z = 0,0,0
    x = input("Enter the First Number: ")
    y = input("Enter the Second Number: ")
    z = input("Enter the Third Number: ")
    numbers = [x,y,z]

    if numbers[0] == numbers[1]:

        if numbers[0] == numbers[2]:

            print("Numbers are Equal which is = ",numbers[0])

        else:

            print("The Maximum number is = ",max(numbers))
            print("The Minimum number is = ",min(numbers))
            
    else:

        print("The Maximum number is = ",max(numbers))
        print("The Minimum number is = ",min(numbers))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    compare()
```

```
import main

while True:
    main.compare()
```